# Ansible: Running shell script using Ansible for Oracle DB

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

When running the below playbook I am not getting desired output as I am getting it from running it manually in oracle environment. Looks like something wrong with the Shell scripting??

```yaml
---
- name: Running a select query on database server
  hosts: localhost # Specify your target server

  tasks:
    - name: running a shell commands for db query
      shell: |
        . oraenv ORCL
        sqlplus / as sysdba << EOF
        SET LINE 60
        COLUMN HOSTNAME FOR A60
        COLUMN INSTANCE_NAME FOR A60
        COLUMN STIME FOR A60
        COLUMN UPTIME FOR A60
        SELECT
          'HOSTNAME : ' || HOST_NAME AS "HOSTNAME"
          ,'INSTANCE NAME : ' || INSTANCE_NAME AS "INSTANCENAME"
          ,'STARTED AT : ' || TO_CHAR (STARTUP_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "STIME"
          ,'UPTIME : ' || FLOOR(SYSDATE - STARTUP_TIME) || ' DAYS(S) ' ||
          TRUNC( 24*((SYSDATE-STARTUP_TIME) -
          TRUNC(SYSDATE-STARTUP_TIME))) || ' HOUR(S) ' ||
          MOD(TRUNC(1440*((SYSDATE-STARTUP_TIME) -
          TRUNC(SYSDATE-STARTUP-TIME))), 60) ||' MINUTE(S) ' ||
          MOD(TRUNC(86400*((SYSDATE-STARTUP_TIME) -
          TRUNC(SYSDATE-STARTUP-TIME))), 60) ||' SECONDS' AS "UPTIME"
        FROM DBA_INSTANCE;
        exit;
        EOF
      register: user_output

    - name: show list of user output
      debug: var=user_output.stdout

  become: True
  become_user: "oracle"
  become_flags: "--login"
  vars:
    ansible_shell_allow_world_readable_temp: true
```

Error I am getting:

```yaml
"user_output.stdout": "ORACLE_SID = [orcl] ? The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /u01/app/oracle\n\nSQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Feb 27 13:59:28 2024\n\nCopyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.\n\n\nConnected to:\nOracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production\nWith the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options\n\nSQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12  FROM DBA_INSTANCE\n     *\nERROR at line 12:\nORA-00942: table or view does not exist\n\n\nSQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production\nWith the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options"
```

Comment: "_I am not getting desired output_", what would be the desired output? "_Looks like something wrong with the Shell scripting_", maybe, how about the error message `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`? Apart from that it is recommend to use the dedicated and specific Ansible Modules for the task, in example [`ansible-oracle-modules`](https://github.com/oravirt/ansible-oracle-modules)

Comment: This is the desired output:'HOSTNAME:'||HOST_NAME
------------------------------------------------------------
'INSTANCENAME:'||INSTANCE_NAME
--------------------------------
STIME
------------------------------------------------------------
UPTIME
------------------------------------------------------------
HOSTNAME : oracletest
INSTANCE NAME : orcl
STARTED AT : 28-FEB-2024 05:19:29
UPTIME : 0 DAYS(S) 0 HOUR(S) 1 MINUTE(S) 19 SECONDS
Can you give the use case for the ansible-oracle-modules

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem in the shell scripting change:
shell: |
. oraenv ORCL
sqlplus / as sysdba << EOF
To:
shell: |
. oraenv ORCL
sqlplus / as sysdba << 'EOF'
The ('') will resolve the problem

Comment: So then essentially a duplicate of [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable); but I can't see anything in your SQL where this would make a difference. Going forward, see also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).